# Calculate row height for HSSFRow

Tags: java, apache-poi, spreadsheet

I'm writing an Excel (xls) sheet with Apache POI 3.13. I set the column width manually. If the content of a cell is too long, I want it to be wrapped and the column height to be adjusted.

If I set the `wrapText` property of the `CellStyle` to `true`, the text does not "flow" out of the cell any more, but how do I set the height of the row to a fitting value?

All approaches I've seen calculate the newline characters in the string.  This is not working for me, since my text does not contain manual newlines.

Comment: `HSSFCellStyle` `.setWrapText(true);` applied to a cell should lead the row with that cell to auto-fit the height if you simply don't explicitly set a height.

Comment: @AxelRichter This is what I do right now, but it doesn’t work - at least not in LibreOffice 5.0.5.2 i will check with excel later

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a LibreOffice bug, because with Excel on a Windows system it looks as expected.